# JVM Crashing EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005)

Tags: java, eclipse, crash, jvm

i've been having some trouble with the jvm crashing lately. This originally started happening when i was running Windows 8.1 however i did a fresh install of windows 7 the other day and the problem has persisted. I have both the JDK and JRE installed and they were installed in that order. Version is 8.0.310.13.

Basically this happens at random times during runtime and has happened for two completely different programs. One of which being Eclipse Luna 4.4.1 and the other being a JAR.

Here are the top halves of two most recent hs_err_pid files from the JAR:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000055e200d5, pid=4764, tid=5664
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_31-b13) (build 1.8.0_31-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.31-b07 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x3e00d5]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x0000000001d17000):  GCTaskThread [stack: 0x0000000012d30000,0x0000000012e30000] [id=5664]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x0000000000000120

Registers:
RAX=0x0000000000000000, RBX=0x00000000f8a9e608, RCX=0x000000013fe514d0, RDX=0x0000000018a40f40
RSP=0x0000000012e2f480, RBP=0x0000000000000011, RSI=0x0000000018a40f40, RDI=0x00000000eb166378
R8 =0x00000000eb166378, R9 =0x000000013fe514d0, R10=0xf8a9e69027f51c1a, R11=0x00000000eb166378
R12=0x0000000011a47136, R13=0x000000000000000d, R14=0x0000000000000000, R15=0x0000000001d05130
RIP=0x0000000055e200d5, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010283

Top of Stack: (sp=0x0000000012e2f480)
0x0000000012e2f480:   0000000000000015 0000000000000003
0x0000000012e2f490:   0000000018a40f40 000000005621d4f0
0x0000000012e2f4a0:   00000000eb160000 0000000000001000
0x0000000012e2f4b0:   0000000018a40f40 0000000055cb9861
0x0000000012e2f4c0:   0000000000000000 0000000018a40f00
0x0000000012e2f4d0:   0000000011a47136 0000000055e201d0
0x0000000012e2f4e0:   00000000eb166050 0000000011a47181
0x0000000012e2f4f0:   0000000018a40f40 0000000081227000
0x0000000012e2f500:   00000000eb166050 0000000055e20d85
0x0000000012e2f510:   000000009522dee0 000007fefd8710dc
0x0000000012e2f520:   00000000e8d0af50 0000000000000005
0x0000000012e2f530:   0000000018a40f40 000007fefd8710dc
0x0000000012e2f540:   00000000808a80ac 0000000055b450c7
0x0000000012e2f550:   00000000808a80b5 00000000808a80b5
0x0000000012e2f560:   0000000080628469 0000000080628469
0x0000000012e2f570:   0000000081226f7c 0000000055b450c7 

Instructions: (pc=0x0000000055e200d5)
0x0000000055e200b5:   eb 04 4c 8b 4f 08 41 81 79 08 00 00 00 c0 0f 83
0x0000000055e200c5:   8d 00 00 00 49 8b 01 4c 8b c7 48 8b d6 49 8b c9
0x0000000055e200d5:   ff 90 20 01 00 00 eb 79 48 8b 03 24 03 3c 03 74
0x0000000055e200e5:   24 4c 8d 0d 23 4d 24 00 4c 8d 05 0c 4e 24 00 48 


Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RBX=0x00000000f8a9e608 is an oop

[error occurred during error reporting (printing register info), id 0xc0000005]

Stack: [0x0000000012d30000,0x0000000012e30000],  sp=0x0000000012e2f480,  free space=1021k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [jvm.dll+0x3e00d5]
V  [jvm.dll+0x3e01d0]
V  [jvm.dll+0x3e0d85]
V  [jvm.dll+0x3d029f]
V  [jvm.dll+0x3e2d52]
V  [jvm.dll+0x3d1b5e]
V  [jvm.dll+0x28576a]
C  [msvcr100.dll+0x21d9f]
C  [msvcr100.dll+0x21e3b]
C  [kernel32.dll+0x159ed]
C  [ntdll.dll+0x2c541]
```

And the second one:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000055ae1460, pid=2688, tid=4288
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_31-b13) (build 1.8.0_31-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.31-b07 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0xa1460]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x000000000208d800):  GCTaskThread [stack: 0x0000000012560000,0x0000000012660000] [id=4288]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x0000000000000008

Registers:
RAX=0x0000000000000000, RBX=0x00000000fe2f6058, RCX=0x00000000fe2f6058, RDX=0x0000000000000000
RSP=0x000000001265f768, RBP=0x0000000011cdef81, RSI=0x000000000210e200, RDI=0x000000009a1e4a18
R8 =0x000000000210e200, R9 =0x0000000000000013, R10=0x00000000fb09e150, R11=0x0000000000000001
R12=0x0000000011cdef1a, R13=0xfe2f72e0fe2f6008, R14=0x0000000000000000, R15=0x0000000002085160
RIP=0x0000000055ae1460, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010246

Top of Stack: (sp=0x000000001265f768)
0x000000001265f768:   0000000055e1fe42 00000000fe2f96a0
0x000000001265f778:   0000000000000006 000000000210e200
0x000000001265f788:   00000000feb45628 00000000fb096160
0x000000001265f798:   0000000000001000 000000000210e200
0x000000001265f7a8:   0000000055b43103 0000000000000000
0x000000001265f7b8:   000000000210e200 0000000011cdef1a
0x000000001265f7c8:   0000000055e201d0 00000000fb034a30
0x000000001265f7d8:   0000000011cdef81 000000000210e200
0x000000001265f7e8:   000000009a1e4a18 00000000fb034a30
0x000000001265f7f8:   0000000055e20d85 00000000e2da6a08
0x000000001265f808:   0000000011c40501 000000000210e200
0x000000001265f818:   0000000000000003 000000000210e200
0x000000001265f828:   0000000055b1c85a 00000000870e421c
0x000000001265f838:   0000000055b450c7 000000000210e200
0x000000001265f848:   0000000055b43103 0000000096a64eb1
0x000000001265f858:   0000000096a64eb1 000000009a1e485c 

Instructions: (pc=0x0000000055ae1460)
0x0000000055ae1440:   48 8d 05 d1 3a 51 00 48 89 44 24 30 e8 8f 40 1d
0x0000000055ae1450:   00 48 81 c4 c0 00 00 00 5b c3 cc cc cc cc cc cc
0x0000000055ae1460:   44 8b 42 08 4c 8b ca 45 85 c0 7e 0e 41 f6 c0 01
0x0000000055ae1470:   75 57 41 c1 f8 03 41 8b c0 c3 79 4d 80 3d 26 2f 


Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RBX=0x00000000fe2f6058 is an oop

[error occurred during error reporting (printing register info), id 0xc0000005]

Stack: [0x0000000012560000,0x0000000012660000],  sp=0x000000001265f768,  free space=1021k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [jvm.dll+0xa1460]
```

Comment: Assuming you're not using some strange JNI stuff, I would suspect that you have bad memory or some such.  The only other time I've ever seen this was in a weirdly concocted stack overflow situation, and that was quite reproducible.

Comment: The JAR i'm using is used by hundreds of other people who haven't experienced such an issue. And the fact that it happens in eclipse as well reduces the possibility of it being an issue in the JAR. I was worried that you might say something like that. I've been meaning to upgrade my pc for a while but haven't had the money. Hopefully there's another explanation :/ Thanks for the quick reply by the way.

Comment: I would suggest you find some sort of memory test program and run it for awhile.

Comment: Will do, running Windows memory diagnostics tool soon. I'll post back with the results. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried installing JDK7 and seeing the problem reproduces there?  If it does, it may indicate missing OS patches.  If it doesn't, then its 99% a JVM bug that you should report given you are using the latest version.

Comment: Unfortunately the JAR i'm using only supports java8 and it's a less common occurence with eclipse.