# Is there any solution to solve JAVA FATAL ERROR in java 8?

Tags: java-8, swt, rcp

I'm working on an RCP java project using swt/jface in the IHM, i'm encountring a serious issue causing the crash of the app.
I tried inspecting the pid file but the last methods in the stack in the pid file are different.
I increased the xmx and xms but the crashs remain, i look for an index helping me solve it but no way.

bellow a snap from the pid file

> ```
> > # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
> > #
> > #  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000005f8c04fa, pid=5268, tid=0x00000000000008c0
> > #
> > # JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_102-b14) (build 1.8.0_102-b14)
> > # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.102-b14 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
> > # Problematic frame:
> > # C  0x000000005f8c04fa
> > #
> > # Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
> > #
> > # If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
> > #   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
> > # The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
> > # See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
> > #
> > 
> > ---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------
> > 
> > Current thread (0x000000000226f800):  JavaThread "main"
> > [_thread_in_native, id=2240,
> > stack(0x00000000026a0000,0x00000000027a0000)]
> > 
> > siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x0000000000000013
> > 
> > Registers: RAX=0x0000000000040b3e, RBX=0x0000000000000002,
> > RCX=0x0000000040b3ed30, RDX=0x0000000000000002 RSP=0x000000000279a700,
> > RBP=0x0000000040b3e000, RSI=0x0000000040b3e000, RDI=0x0000000000000000
> > R8 =0x0000000000000001, R9 =0x0000000000000001,
> > R10=0x0000000004deb3c9, R11=0x0000000004deb398 R12=0x00000000609a8730,
> > R13=0x0000000000000000, R14=0x0000000000000001, R15=0x0000000000000000
> > RIP=0x000000005f8c04fa, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010202
> > 
> > Top of Stack: (sp=0x000000000279a700) 0x000000000279a700:  
> > 000000000279a848 0000000000000000 0x000000000279a710:  
> > 000000000226f800 000000000279a7d8 0x000000000279a720:  
> > 000000000226f800 000000000279a808 0x000000000279a730:  
> > 0000000000000000 0000000000470000 0x000000000279a740:  
> > 000000000279a7d8 000000005f8bf2e3 0x000000000279a750:  
> > 0000000000000002 0000000040b3ed30 0x000000000279a760:  
> > 000000000279a7f0 0000000000470000 0x000000000279a770:  
> > 0000000000000000 0000000004deb447 0x000000000279a780:  
> > 0000000024385638 00000006dce5dbb0 0x000000000279a790:  
> > 0000000000421054 0000000002c06f44 0x000000000279a7a0:  
> > 0000000000000002 0000000004e7aef4 0x000000000279a7b0:  
> > 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0x000000000279a7c0:  
> > 0000000036bb84e0 0000000000000000 0x000000000279a7d0:  
> > 000000000279a868 00000006dd0f16a0 0x000000000279a7e0:  
> > 00000006dd0f16a0 0000000002a77f10 0x000000000279a7f0:  
> > 000000000279a868 0000000002a77f10 
> > 
> > Instructions: (pc=0x000000005f8c04fa) 0x000000005f8c04da:   81 e3 ff
> > 07 00 00 48 03 db 49 39 b4 dc d0 08 00 0x000000005f8c04ea:   00 75 28
> > 49 8b 9c dc d8 08 00 00 48 85 db 74 20 0x000000005f8c04fa:   0f b6 43
> > 11 41 3b c0 75 17 41 83 f8 01 0f 85 80 0x000000005f8c050a:   01 00 00
> > ff 43 18 e9 78 01 00 00 48 8b 5c 24 50 
> > 
> > 
> > Register to memory mapping:
> > 
> > RAX=0x0000000000040b3e is an unknown value RBX=0x0000000000000002 is
> > an unknown value RCX=0x0000000040b3ed30 is an unknown value
> > RDX=0x0000000000000002 is an unknown value RSP=0x000000000279a700 is
> > pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000000226f800
> > RBP=0x0000000040b3e000 is an unknown value RSI=0x0000000040b3e000 is
> > an unknown value RDI=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value R8
> > =0x0000000000000001 is an unknown value R9 =0x0000000000000001 is an unknown value R10=0x0000000004deb3c9 is at entry_point+73 in
> > (nmethod*)0x0000000004deb210 R11=0x0000000004deb398 is at
> > entry_point+24 in (nmethod*)0x0000000004deb210 R12=0x00000000609a8730
> > is an unknown value R13=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
> > R14=0x0000000000000001 is an unknown value R15=0x0000000000000000 is
> > an unknown value
> > 
> > 
> > Stack: [0x00000000026a0000,0x00000000027a0000], 
> > sp=0x000000000279a700,  free space=1001k Native frames: (J=compiled
> > Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code) C 
> > 0x000000005f8c04fa C  0x000000005f8bf2e3 C  0x0000000004deb447
> > 
> > Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code) J 10363
> > org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.HeapAlloc(JII)J (0 bytes) @
> > 0x0000000004deb3c9 [0x0000000004deb380+0x49] j 
> > org.eclipse.swt.widgets.CoolBar.createItem(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/CoolItem;I)V+114
> > j 
> > org.eclipse.swt.widgets.CoolItem.<init>(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/CoolBar;I)V+17
> > j 
> > fr.ifp.temisflow.api.basintools.ui.ui.widget.CoolItemFactory.createCoolItem(ILorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Control;II)Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/CoolItem;+58
> ```

and my VM arguments et environment variables are:

```
> VM Arguments: jvm_args:
> -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,suspend=y,address=localhost:58325 -Xms400m -Xmx4000m -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+AggressiveOpts -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252  java_command: org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main -launcher

> -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -nl en_GB -consoleLog java_class_path (initial):
> C:\Users\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\.bundle_pool\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
> Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD
> 
> Environment Variables: PATH=C:/Program
> Files/Java/jre1.8.0_102/bin/server;C:/Program
> Files/Java/jre1.8.0_102/bin;C:/Program
> Files/Java/jre1.8.0_102/lib/amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common
> Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\intel64\mpirt;C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared
> Libraries\redist\intel64\compiler;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
> Files (x86)\WinMerge;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common
> Files\SYSTEM\MSMAPI\1036;C:\Users\eclipse;
> USERNAME=** OS=Windows_NT PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6
> Model 26 Stepping 5, GenuineIntel
> 
> 
> 
> ---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------
> 
> OS: Windows 7 , 64 bit Build 7601 (6.1.7601.23572)
> 
> CPU:total 4 (4 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 26
> stepping 5, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1,
> sse4.2, popcnt, ht, tsc, tscinvbit, tscinv
> 
> Memory: 4k page, physical 12580408k(5019496k free), swap
> 25158956k(16067112k free)
> 
> vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.102-b14) for
> windows-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_102-b14), built on Jun 22 2016 13:15:21 by
> "java_re" with MS VC++ 10.0 (VS2010)
```

i also looked through the log in the the .metadata in the workspace but no logs during the crash.

Is there any possible solution or steps or rule skout to solve the java fatal error in java 8 ?

Comment: You haven't given us anything like enough information to be able to help. What is the crash? Give us more details. Eclipse RCPs with SWT and JFace generally work fine with Java 8.

Comment: it's a heavy e3 app, i can reproduce the crash by trying to open an editor but there no apparent trace to help us to detect how and where the crash occurs, i run yourkit to detect abnormal memory behavior but all the charts seem to be ok.

Comment: Look for a .log file in the workspace .metdata directory.

Answer (score 0):

Check your RAM.

I was suffering that very same error `EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005)`, a couple times a day, for weeks, until I run a memory diagnostics tool and found that one of my RAM modules was faulty.

Reference: [JVM Crashing EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28333982/jvm-crashing-exception-access-violation-0xc0000005)

ANNIVERSARY EDIT: It's been a bit over a year since I solved the problem by replacing the faulty RAM module. Now, for a couple weeks I've been experiencing the same error, again. I just run the memory diagnostics tool and BAM! It detected memory errors, again. So, seriously people: check your RAM.

Comment: i just run the windows tool to diagnostic the memory but no errors were found, and i already run yourkit to see the memory (heap and non heap ) charts but no memory has exceeded his allocation, i wonder if anyone has encountred this issue where no memory problems were found.